# JavaScript Memory Leak issue for page running 24 X7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks

I have a page in PHP/HTML, which is puling some data via Ajax. The functionality needs to pull data every 2 sec( x 9 request) and every 10 sec ( x 9 request) and we need to keep this page running 24/7 . But after few hours the memory used by browser starts increasing and keeps on increasing. And later it get crashed. So i need to fix the memory leaks in JavaScript.

Anyone who had already worked with JavaScript memory leaks can solve this quickly. Please share your experience as i need to fix the memory leaks.

I had tried my best to make null of variables created.

The below is ajax request which is hitted every 2 seconds with 9 request (different parameters)

```
 setInterval(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $(".div1").load("xyz.php?param1=param1&param2=param2", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                xhr = null;
                responseTxt = null;
                statusTxt = null;
            });
        },2000);
```

and below is ajax request which is hitted every 10 seconds with 9 request (different parameters)

```
setInterval(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
            $(".grid").load("response.php?param1=param1&param2=param2", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                if(statusTxt == "success"){
                    $('.rotate').delay(200).rotaterator({fadeSpeed:1000, pauseSpeed:1000}); 
                }else{
                    var under_maintenance = '<tr><td colspan="6">';
                    under_maintenance = under_maintenance + 'System Under Maintenance.';
                    under_maintenance = under_maintenance + '</td></tr>';
                    $(".grid").html(under_maintenance);
                    under_maintenance = null
                }
                xhr = null;
                responseTxt = null;
                statusTxt = null;
            });
        },10000);
```

Please look for above and help me as the page needs to run 24 x 7 and the memory leak for browser is eventually making the page crashing.

Comment: 1. What is `rotaterator`? 2. Why in the world whould you run a 24x7 service in JavaScript?